# How to make a mesh change its shape into a premodeled mesh in animation

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, mesh

I typically want a mesh to change its shape and texture in animation ,into another mesh

like a kind a liquid taking shapes of different objects

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with "which wont be rendered" ?

Comment: Sorry i edited the question

Comment: You should look into "Shape Keys"

Comment: use lattices that you shape then pass the object through it, or the other way round.